# Can you get promoted to Associate Professor at the University of Sydney if you have good research outputs but not ARC grant?

Tags: funding, australia, promotion

Currently considering resigning from an associate prof position in the US to take up a lecturer one at Sydney Uni but am worried that promotion might be very hard to get without ARC funding. No one in my field (humanities) at USYD has ever received an ARC grant, for various reasons. The Australian academic system seems to heavily rely on those grants. Has anyone had experience with this situation or can give more insight?

Comment: Lecturers get grants in Australia?

Comment: A lecturer in the Australian system is equivalent to a tenured assistant professor in the US system.

Comment: You really need data from Sydney to answer this question in terms that will be helpful to you. The narrow answer seems to be "yes" since you state that there have been promotions in the humanities with no ARC funding.

Comment: Tenured assistant professor is a bit of an oxymoron in the US, actually, but yes, "Lecturer" in the US isn't at all like some other places.

Comment: Just to be clearer: People do get ARC grants in the humanities - just not in my small subfield.

Comment: You can probably find out this info for yourself.  Go thru' the AProfs at SydUni at determine how many were promoted with/without an ARC DP; say in the last five years.

Comment: I've voted to close as this is too specific for a reliable answer here. There aren't enough of us here with the needed expertise to answer it with something you could base a career change on. But, I'd expect promotion to be difficult in any case. High standards and all that. Takes work, like everywhere.

Comment: Not an answer as I think you need information from people familiar with the specifics of how things operate in your department & field, but USyd publishes its policy on promotion [here](https://www.sydney.edu.au/policies/showdoc.aspx?recnum=PDOC2014/342&RendNum=0). For promotion to Level D some record of getting external funding appears to be mandatory, though this could potentially be from sources other than the ARC. Of course, much will depend on how these rules are interpreted in practice.

Comment: Though actually, "Lecturer" is usually Level B so maybe you're talking about promotion to Level C. In that case I interpret the rules as saying you only need to have *applied* for grants, and those applications don't need to have been successful.

Comment: Promotion in the Australian system doesn't work like in the US system.  It's quite common for people to never be promoted and remain as a Lecturer their entire career.  In some universities or departments, there is no promotion; if there is a position open with a higher title, then you can apply for it along with everyone else, and if you are successful, you would 'quit' your job as Lecturer to 'take up' a 'new' job as Associate Professor.

Comment: Thank you so much for this useful info, avid!

Comment: Alexander Woo: I don't think this is quite accurate. At least not in Group of 8 universities.

Comment: @Buffy I don't agree this is too specific.  Anyone familiar with Australian universities would know that promotion would be hard to get without funding.

Comment: @LeonoraCarrington Just to add: it is absolutely normal and reasonable to ask whoever is hiring you to explain the promotion process and what that is likely to look like in your specific circumstances. (Though be aware that people put who are trying to hire you have an incentive to put a positive spin on things!)

Comment: I attempted to generalize the title question a bit. We don't generally take questions about institutions below the national level; if you want to know a particular institution's policies, you should ask them. But the more generalized question about tenured positions in Australian academia generally is probably on topic.

Comment: Also, I recommend you [edit] your question to explain better: what is an ARC grant, what is USYD, what is the job title you are hoping to be promoted to, etc. If it is true that a "lecturer" position in Australia is non-tenured but tenure track, I would state that as well, and explain why it's so important to you to get promoted (what benefit does being promoted entail? More money?)

Comment: I thought Australia got rid of tenure like the UK?  (Of course, general employment law provides (for people in a continuing position) protections much stronger than in the US.)

Comment: Wait... is it about _tenure_ (or equivalent), or about _promotion_ (not necessarily related to "tenure")? Please advise.

Comment: @cag51 The concept of tenure does not apply to Australia.

Comment: @cag51 The term "R1" is also not so appropriate.  Perhaps "Group of Eight" would be better.  Keep in mind Australia only has about 30 universities and they're quite similar.  https://go8.edu.au/

Comment: @LeonoraCarrington Consider asking your prospective university's NTEU chapter for advice.  A good head of school will also provide accurate information, but I don't know your head of school.

Comment: @cag51: would you mind reverting my question to its original content and removing your edits, please? Your edits have introduced many inaccuracies and are preventing me from receiving adequate answers. Thank you. Anonymous Physicist is correct in that there is no "tenure" in Australia and we are talking about Group of 8 - not R1.

Comment: @LeonoraCarrington - you may hit the [edit] button and make further edits to correct inaccuracies and provide more information. However, if you revert the question to its original form, the question is likely to be closed -- we can answer questions about Australian academia generally, but questions about a single university's policies are off-topic here. Also, please see the other requests for clarifications in this thread and consider addressing those with your edit as well.

Answer (score 1):

Promotion to associate professor at any Australian university without receiving a major grant from a well-known government funding agency is quite unlikely.  ARC provides much less money to humanities than other fields. As far as I know, the other funding agencies do not fund humanities at all.

Colleagues told me humanities academics rarely get promotions.  In all fields, a substantial portion of career advancement is obtained by changing universities.

You can search grants for yourself.
https://dataportal.arc.gov.au/NCGP/Web/Grant/Grants

Unlike the USA, never receiving a promotion to full professor is considered normal in Australian universities.

Comment: Also, the progression is lecturer -> senior lecturer -> associate professor, except when it's not.

Comment: The last sentence is very true. I know 2 professors. One of them went from PhD graduate to full-professor within 10 years. He also received DECRA and FF. While it took the other professor who got no major grant almost 15 years to get promoted to A/Prof.

Comment: Thank you! This is really helpful!